# C# WIndows phone 8.1 Listview StackPanel size

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I wonder if someone can help mw with my app...
Then so....First from all, i'm making Windows Phone 8.1 application and i use C#.
I'm trying to fix screen size for differt device(Start from 4,5 inch screen to 6inch screen).
From start i try put in Stackpanel many thinks :D
For 4,5inch screen now works perfect!
But when i try app in 6 inch screen then start magic...
This is how looks 4,5 inch screen:
[4,5 inch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSGGV.png)

But this is 6 inch screen:
[6inch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL6N8.png)

First problem:
*Images is too hudge

Second:
*Can see the difference..

```
        <ScrollViewer
        Margin="0,0,0,-1160" 
        Grid.Row="2"
        ZoomMode="Enabled" 
        MinZoomFactor="1.1" 
        MaxZoomFactor="2.6">


        <StackPanel
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Height="1284">

            <!--Probleme ir Ar List view-->
            <ListView Height="587"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      IsRightTapEnabled="False" 
                      IsTapEnabled="False">

                <StackPanel
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock  
                        Text="Hole 1" 
                        FontSize="30"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        Width="369"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <Image x:Name="img1"
                       Source="Courses/Yellow/hole1.png"  
                       IsTapEnabled="False" 
                       IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" 
                       Stretch="Fill"/>


                <TextBlock Text="Max points from task : 4"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="20" 
                        Height="24"
                        Width="369"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                <Image Source="Assets/question.png"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                    PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed"/>

                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                    <StackPanel
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Button x:Name="hit1" 
                            Content="Hit" 
                            Click="Button_Click_3"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel>
                    <Button x:Name="miss1" 
                            Content="Miss" 
                            Margin="125,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_4"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>


                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="30" 
                        Width="480" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="Hole 2"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <StackPanel
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image x:Name="img2"
                       Source="Courses/Yellow/hole2.png" 
                       Stretch="Fill"
                       IsTapEnabled="False" 
                       IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="20" 
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Width="480">
                        <Run Text="Max points from task : 3"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image Source="Assets/question.png"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                    PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed_1"/>


                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="hit2" 
                            Content="Hit" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_5"/>

                    <Button x:Name="miss2"
                            Content="Miss" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="90,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_6"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="30" 
                        Width="480" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="Hole 3"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image x:Name="img3"
                       Source="Courses/Yellow/hole3.png" 
                        Stretch="Fill"
                       IsTapEnabled="False" 
                       IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"/>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="20"
                        Width="480"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Run Text="Max points from task : 4"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image Source="Assets/question.png"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                    PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed_3"/>


                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="hit3" 
                            Content="Hit" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_7"/>

                    <Button x:Name="miss3"    
                            Content="Miss" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            Margin="90,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_8"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="30" 
                        Width="480" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="Hole 4"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image x:Name="img4"
                       Source="Courses/Yellow/hole4.png" 
                        Stretch="Fill"
                       IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"
                       IsTapEnabled="False"/>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="20"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Width="480">
                        <Run Text="Max points from task : 3"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image Source="Assets/question.png"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="20,0,0,0"
                    PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed_2"/>


                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="hit4" 
                            Content="Hit" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                            Click="Button_Click_9"/>

                    <Button x:Name="miss4"    
                            Content="Miss" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="90,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_10"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="30" 
                        Width="480"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="Hole 5"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image x:Name="img5"
                       Source="Courses/Yellow/hole5.png" 
                        Stretch="Fill"
                      IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False"/>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="20"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Width="480">
                        <Run Text="Max points from task : 4"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image Source="Assets/question.png"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="20,0,0,0"
                    PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed_4"/>


                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="hit5" 
                            Content="Hit" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_11"/>

                    <Button x:Name="miss5"    
                            Content="Miss" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="90,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_12"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="30" 
                        Width="480" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="Hole 6"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image x:Name="img6"
                       Source="Courses/Yellow/hole6.png" 
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False"/>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="20"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Width="480">
                        <Run Text="Max points from task : 4"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image Source="Assets/question.png"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="20,0,0,0"
                    PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed_5"/>


                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="hit6" 
                            Content="Hit" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_13"/>

                    <Button x:Name="miss6"    
                            Content="Miss" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="90,0,0,0" 
                            Click="Button_Click_14"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="30" 
                        Width="480"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="Hole 7"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image x:Name="img7"
                       Source="Courses/Yellow/hole7.png" 
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False"/>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="20"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Width="480">
                        <Run Text="Max points from task : 5"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image Source="Assets/question.png"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="20,0,0,0"
                    PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed_6"/>


                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="hit7" 
                            Content="Hit" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_15"/>

                    <Button x:Name="miss7"    
                            Content="Miss" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="90,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_16"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="30" 
                        Width="480" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="Hole 8"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image x:Name="img8"
                       Source="Courses/Yellow/hole8.png" 
                        Stretch="Fill"
                       IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False"/>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="20" 
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Width="480">
                        <Run Text="Max points from task : 3"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image Source="Assets/question.png"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="20,0,0,0"
                    PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed_7"/>


                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="hit8" 
                            Content="Hit" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_17"/>

                    <Button x:Name="miss8"    
                            Content="Miss" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="90,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_18"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="30" 
                        Width="480"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        TextAlignment="Center">
                        <Run Text="Hole 9"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image x:Name="img9"
                       Source="Courses/Yellow/hole9.png" 
                        Stretch="Fill"
                       IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False"/>

                <TextBlock
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontSize="20" 
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Width="480">
                        <Run Text="Max points from task : 5"/>
                </TextBlock>

                <Image Source="Assets/question.png"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="20,0,0,0"
                    PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed_8"/>


                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button x:Name="hit9" 
                            Content="Hit" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            Click="Button_Click_19"/>

                    <Button x:Name="miss9"    
                            Content="Miss" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="90,0,0,0" 
                            Click="Button_Click_20"/>

                </StackPanel>


                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button Content="Main Page" 
                        Click="Button_Click_1"/>

                    <Button Content="Save" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Click="Button_Click_21" />

                    <Button Content="Go to Hole 10 to 18"
                            Click="Button_Click"                                
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                </StackPanel>

            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I need set Listview widht or somethink else?
Any idea?

P.S sorry abou my bad english knowledge:(

**EDIT:**
I fix by myself:)
i was problem there:

```
                <ListView Height="587"
                      IsRightTapEnabled="False" 
                      IsTapEnabled="False"
                      Margin="0,0,50,0">
```

Problem with Margin, i added to my code:)